# New to batch programming. Help on setting new variables

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I am trying to perform the below. If i try setting ACCNAME with any variable letter rather than /p I am facing a syntax error. Can someone tell me why I cannot use any other variable letter please?

```
@echo off
echo -create
set /p PROGRAM= What do you want to do?:
goto %PROGRAM%

:create
set /b ACCNAME= Please type in your username:
echo %ACCNAME% > usernames.txt
pause
```

Comment: You have a typo: `set /b` should be `set /p`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/p` is not a variable letter, but rather a switch which tells "prompt user to enter the new value of `PROGRAM` variable".

Without `/p`, `set PROGRAM= What do you want to do?:`, would just set the value of **variable `PROGRAM`** to the string `What do you want to do?:`.

And you get syntax error because there's no `/b` switch for the `SET` command.

For full syntax of `SET` command, use `set /?`.

Comment: Indeed. `/P` is not the variable, ACCNAME is. And if you want it to be just one letter, you can do that. Additionally, you can call `setlocal` to prevent your command session to be polluted with variables you only need in the script itself.